# Access Level at SSRS reports with Network Credentials

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have design level problem. I am struggling to find the right solution. 
I am new to SSRS.
I have a requirement to create SSRS reports for internal teams in the company(Basically for Marketing, Sales, Billing etc) where one department team cannot access other department reports only admin can able to access all the reports. this reports URL we need to invoke in our company website. 
Firstly IS there a way to differentiate the departments with out a new credentials given to them ? Anything like asking them to provide Network credentials? any information would be Appreciated.

Comment: Do your users have separate permissions within Windows? I know you can protect reports by placing access restrictions based on the windows user groups.

Answer (score 2):

We are talking about viewing reports in the web view/report builder, right.

One option is to create a folder for specific users and link or create the report in that folder. Or deny general access to the folder and then subscribe specific users.

Or implement user based authentication on the report itself.

References:

- https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/ssrs-how-create-reports-user-protect-sensitive-data
- [Setting Item-Level Permissions on a Report Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337471%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Setting Permissions on Specific Items](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337494%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)